# Apache flink keyby function with field expression

Tags: apache-flink, aggregation

Samples Messages:

```
>{"sensor":"temp1", "value":12.0, "timestamp":19200230}
>{"sensor":"temp1", "value":12.0, "timestamp":19200230}
>{"sensor":"temp1", "value":12.0, "timestamp":19200230}
>{"sensor":"temp2", "value":5, "timestamp":19200230}
>{"sensor":"temp2", "value":5, "timestamp":19200230}
```

I am trying to build an stream aggregation with a keyby method.

```
DataStream<Message> messageSumStream = messageStream.keyBy("sensor").timeWindowAll(Time.minutes(5)).sum("value");
```

I expected

```
{"sensor": "temp1", "value": 36.000000, "timestamp":19200230 }
{"sensor": "temp2", "value": 10.000000, "timestamp":19200230 }
```

But got:

```
{"sensor": "temp1", "value": 46.000000, "timestamp":19200230 }
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [timeWindowAll](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStream.html#timeWindowAll-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time-) from DataStream class instead of [timeWindow](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/KeyedStream.html#timeWindow-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time-) from KeyedDataStream, resulting a code that ignores the keyBy.

Try this:

```
DataStream<Message> messageSumStream = messageStream.keyBy("sensor").timeWindow(Time.minutes(5)).sum("value");
```